# Falling Max Swift Combine Publisher

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

I'm working on a publisher for Swift/Combine

Given a stream of inputs, I want to record the max value.
If the next number is lower, take one from the last recorded max value and emit that.

```
Input:  [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,3,1]
Output: [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,2]
```

I can do this easily with the following code, however, I really don't like the instance variable

```
var lastMaxInstanceValue: Float = 0

publisher
.map { newValue
  if newValue > lastMaxInstanceValue {
    lastMaxInstanceValue = newValue
  } else {
    lastMaxInstanceValue = max(0, lastMaxInstanceValue - 1)
  }
}
.assign(to: \.percentage, on: self)
.store(in: &cancellables)
```

So I wrote a publisher/subscriber here which encapsulates the `map` part above:

https://github.com/nthState/FallingMaxPublisher

With my publisher, the code turns into:

```
publisher
.fallingMax()
.assign(to: \.percentage, on: self)
.store(in: &cancellables)
```

My question is, is my GitHub publisher necessary? Can the value I want be calculated without having the extra variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scan` operator to achieve this. `Scan` stores an accumulated value computed from each upstream value and the currently accumulated value. You do however, need to give it an initial value; based on your example I used `0`:

```
publisher
   .scan(0, { max, value in
      value >= max ? value : max - 1
   })
```

---

You can implement a `fallingMax` operator for `SignedInteger`s - as in your github - like so:

```
extension Publisher where Output: SignedInteger {
    func fallingMax(initial: Output = 0, 
                    fadeDownAmount: Output = 1
                   ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {

        self.scan(initial, { max, value in
            value >= max ? value : max - fadeDownAmount
        })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

---

As per @Rob's suggestion, if you don't want to supply an initial value, which would instead use the first value as the initial output, you can use an `Optional` (notice the `.compactMap` to bring it back to non-optional):

```
extension Publisher where Output: SignedInteger {
    func fallingMax(initial: Output? = .none, 
                    fadeDownAmount: Output = 1
                   ) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {

        self.scan(initial, { max, value in
            max.map { value >= $0 ? value : $0 - fadeDownAmount } ?? value
        })
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to avoid magical sentinel values, one could make it optional, e.g. `.scan(Int?.none) { max($0 ?? $1, $1) }`

Comment: @Rob, definitely a good point (and needs to be followed by `.compactMap`), but it subtly changes OP's desired functionality if doesn't start from `0`, so I didn't do it.